# React JSX Syntax

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am using the code below to create a react component.

```js
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
      {props.name}
    </button>
  )
}


class LikeButton extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('ciao');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button handleClick={this.handleClick}
        name='Get' />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, document.getElementById('buttons'));
```

I tried the code with sandbox and it works perfectly. The problem is when I run my code, I get an error syntax in the third line of my Button function.

At first, I thought it was an error related to babel but I am using the CDN and it is supposed to work.

Comment: what error do you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Babel from a CDN for experimentation you need to make sure your `script` tag has the attribute `type="text/babel"` as well.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="buttons"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.name}</button>;
}

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('ciao');
  }

  render() {
    return <Button handleClick={this.handleClick} name='Get' />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, document.getElementById('buttons'));
</script>
```

Comment: I went to back to this answer and tried using this answer. copied the code but nothing is rendered. I don't get why though...